# How to enable the use of the gui resources on mac

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, macports, ttk

I am having a problem with tkinter.ttk on mac. I am using macports and python3.1. When I try to use tkinter.ttk I get very old looking gui elements.

eg: I get this
[image]
Instead of this:
[image]

The code I used is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Hello World").grid()
root.mainloop()
```

I would be happy to provide any information from my computer needed to answer this question. As I am a novice programer please tell me where to find said information.

> After a bit of digging I found this:
>       Python 3.1.2 (r312:79147, Jan 16 2011, 08:02:01)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple
>   Inc. build 5664)] on darwin Type
>   "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.
>
> ```
> ->>> import tkinter.test.test_ttk.test_style
> ```
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/test/test_ttk/test_style.py",
>   line 8, in 
>           requires('gui')   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/test/support.py",
>   line 215, in requires
>           raise ResourceDenied(msg) test.support.ResourceDenied: Use of
>   the `gui' resource not enabled
>
>       ->>> The error I have has something to do with the fact that
>   "Use of the`gui' resource is not
>   enabled".

**If two more people confirm that the code in blockquotes has nothing to do with the problem I will delete it from the question.**

I have a Macbook 5,2 with Snow Leopard installed. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, Marlen

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my ttk widgets look modern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073773/how-do-i-make-my-ttk-widgets-look-modern)

Comment: The link you suggest is the correct question. The question I posed here while interesting is not the problem I really needed to solve.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely that this is related. You run the test from the Python command line, it needs to be enabled first, which is done by:

```
from test import support
support.use_resources = ['gui']
```

Then you can:

```
import tkinter.test.test_ttk.test_style
```

And see what it says (mine says nothing, but I'm on Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code and it works. Sadly it doesn't fix the problem. I will fix my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Marlen T. B.: Yes, that you can't run the tests in the way you tried is obviously not related to your actual problem. :-) Try showing some minimal code that has the problem, and maybe a screenshot of the "old looking" elements. You are probably better off doing this in a new question, and selecting my answer as selected. New questions get more eyes than old ones.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing that right now. I will try to stick to this question for now though.

Comment: I will try to re-post under a better title as per your advice.